# How to get Google Form field value and use it in Appscript to send an email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'd like to get the value that I set on the Google Form Drop down lists named "**mail lists**".

What I'm trying to do is send a customize email to the value that I select.

My form is look like this:

[image]

Now, once I select an option, I'd like to send an email to it. Here's my appscript code in the Forms:

```
function sendEmail(e) {
  
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email.html");
  var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent();
  
  var emailTo = e.response.getRespondentEmail(); // how do I get the dropdown value here?
  Logger.log(emailTo)
  var subject = "sample subject";
  var textBody = "this is a body";
  var options = { htmlBody: htmlText };
  
  if(emailTo !== undefined){
    
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, textBody, options)
  }
}
```

**Question is how do I set the emailTo to the value that I select in the dropdown?**

My spreadsheet is look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
e.values[1]
```

the **values** property holds an array of all the responses submitted with the form where `e.values[0]` is the timestamp and e.values[1] is the selected dropdown value

Comment: should I use just like this var `emailTo = e.values[1];` then I get this error TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Comment: Use it in the spreadsheet not the form. Note: there’s two onFormSubmits

Comment: Yes, you have to set up a trigger for onFormSubmit

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

Assuming that `sendEmail(e)` is an `On form submit` trigger within your form then you can get the first response item (in your case, the email) like that:

```
var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
var email = itemResponses[0].getResponse();  // returns the email if given
```

---

### Solution:

```
function sendEmail(e) {
  
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email.html");
  var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent();
  
  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var emailTo = itemResponses[0].getResponse();  // returns the email if given

  var subject = "sample subject";
  var textBody = "this is a body";
  var options = { htmlBody: htmlText };
  
  if(emailTo !== undefined){
    
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, textBody, options)
  }
}
```